# chrome extension chrome.storage.local default settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am developing a Chrome extension for my workplace, and have a number of default settings that are created in chrome.storage.local upon installation, using the event chrome.runtime.onInstalled.

However, I'm pretty sure this means that whenever I push a new version of the extension, users' settings will be overwritten by the defaults. I found the Object.assign method which looks like it can fix this problem, but I cannot figure out how to test my code without resorting to *actually updating the extension*.

Uninstalling the unpacked version of the extension seems to cause its chrome.storage.local keys to be destroyed (I could be wrong about this), so I cannot verify upon re-installation whether it would retain any settings I had previously changed.

My current "onInstalled" code looks something like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(["options"], function(r){

        let defaults = {
            option1: 2000,
            option2: true,
            option3: false,
            option4: ""
        },
        current = r.options,
        newSettings = Object.assign(defaults,current);

        chrome.storage.local.set({
            options: newSettings
        });
    });
});
```

One follow-up question: is it necessary to namespace my options, or is chrome.storage.local set up so that same-name settings in different extensions would not interfere with each other?

Comment: 1) Check the [reason](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) parameter. 2) browser storage is per *origin* and your extension has its own like chrome-extension://xxxxx

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the info. To be clear, for 1) does this mean that uninstalling the unpacked extension does NOT destroy the "options" object in chrome.storage?

Comment: I don't see how it's related. Uninstalling an extension destroys its local data.